# ajax get 404 not found when try to find data from database using button and primary key

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

so I want to get data from database using button and primary key like this:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
{
    echo "<tr class = 'raw' id = 'data'>";
    echo "  <td><button onclick = 'gettahun(".$row['kdTahun'].")' data-dismiss='modal'>#</button></td>";
    echo "  <td class = 'kdTAHUN'>".$row['kdTahun']."</td>";
    echo "  <td class = 'TAHUN'>".$row['tahun']."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

and there is function gettahun()

```
function getfakultas(pilih)
{
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "routes/getfakulas.php",
        data: {"kdFakultas":pilih},
        success: function(hasil)
        {
            var result = $.parseJSON(hasil);
            $("#kdFakultas").val(result.KDFAKULTAS);
            $("#Fakultas").val(result.FAKULTAS);
            $('#kdFakultas').attr('readonly', true);
        },
        error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
           if(xhr.status==404) {
               alert(thrownError);
          }
       }
    });
}
```

and my php to prosses input and send data to textbox is:

```
<?php
session_start();
$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$pass = "";
$name = "buku_tahunan";

$koneksi = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass,$name);

if(mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    die("koneksi DB Gagal".mysqli_connect_error());
}
$kdfakultas = $_GET["kdFakultas"];

$sql="SELECT * FROM `fakultas` WHERE kdFakultas = '$kdfakultas'";

$query = mysqli_query($koneksi,$sql);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
{
    $output =  array('KDFAKULTAS'=>$row['kdFakultas'],
             'FAKULTAS'=>$row['nmFakultas']);
    echo json_encode($output);
}
 ?>
```

but I got an error alert, it say "not found". and in the concole I see this error:
[image]

so whats the real cause of these error?

Comment: Is there a `getfakulas.php` file in `routes` folder ?

Comment: yes, getfakulas.php file is in routes folder

Comment: I you access the link directly in your browser you don't have `404` ?

Comment: get error 404 when I try to access that's link directly to my browser

Comment: are you trying this in laravel.?

Comment: shouldn't it be "routes/getfakultas.php" and not "routes/getfakulas.php" - missing t?

Comment: after I try  and do some update. I can accces the link directly

Comment: @Oliver ah.., thank you. finally I can figure out the real cause of error

Comment: @Jansebastian You'r welcome